# Creating a SQLite DB with EF Core Framework (one-to-many connection)

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I have models like the MS example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many):

```
public class AdminModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Hostname")]
    public EndpointAdminModel? Hostname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public required string Username { get; set; }

    public Boolean Enabled { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? EnabledUntil { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }

    public string? ModifiedBy { get; set; }

}
```

and:

```
public class EndpointAdminModel
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Hostname")]
    public required string Hostname { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
    public ICollection<AdminModel>? Admin { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Enabled")]
    public Boolean Enabled { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? Created { get; set; }

    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }

    public string? ModifiedBy { get; set; }

}
```

Now I want to create a one-to-many connection:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EndpointAdminModel>()
                .HasMany<AdminModel>(d => d.Admin)
                .WithOne(dm => dm.Hostname) 
                .HasForeignKey(d => new { d.Hostname, d.Username });
```

But this gives me the error:
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'The property or navigation 'Hostname' cannot be added to the 'AdminModel' type because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on the 'AdminModel' type.'

When I change .WithOne(dm => dm.Hostname) with .WithOne() I don't receive the error anymore, but

```
public BeyondTrustDBContext(DbContextOptions<BeyondTrustDBContext> options)
    : base(opAny idea what I am doing wrong?tions)
{
    Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```

is failing because of the properties I am using in the model. I know, SQLite only supports a few, but I feel like for the 1000 records I need to store SQlite is the best option.

Can anybody help me with that?

Edit:
I think I had to add a real foreign key-name:

```
public required string Hostname { get; set; } // Foreign key
```

and after that:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<EndpointAdminModel>()
        .HasMany<AdminModel>(d => d.Admin)
        .WithOne(s => s.Host)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.Hostname);
```

seems to work.

Comment: To answer your own question, post an answer yourself, not an edit to the question. By the way, C# naming convention is to use plural for collections, so your ICollection<AdminModel> should be called `Admins` (it naturally implies that one endpint has many admins), not `Admin` (it naturally implies one Endpoint has one Admin)

Comment: Maybe also think about the rest of the names you're creating - an endpoint has a Hostname that is a string (seems reasonable) but an Admin has a Hostname that is an Endpoint (seems unreasonable). We don't normally suffix our EF entities with the word "Model". EndPointAdminModel seems more like it would be the entity that decomposes a M:M relationship between admins and endpoints, where an admin looks after many endpoints and an endpoint has multiple admins, hence Hostname should be in its own Endpoint entity. Perhaps avoid strings for PKs

Comment: Thanks @HasBeanCounter. I will change the naming convention. I just do it once every couple of years so I usually forget about the right way.

Comment: Incidentally if you only infrequently work with C#, EF, etc you might be able to take some pain out of your life by using the VS extension EFCore Power Tools - I tend to create my database side first, setting up tables and relationships etc, then jsut tell EFCPT to reverse it into a context and models for me. It is just a front end for functions built into EF, with some added bells and whistles to make an easier life. I don't think I've manually altered a context fleunt builder setup in years now; it Just Works when you get EF to reverse the DB, and a bit more painlessly than Code First IMHO

Answer (score 0):

As written in the edit part:

I think I had to add a real foreign key-name:

public required string Hostname { get; set; } // Foreign key

and after that:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EndpointAdminModel>()
    .HasMany<AdminModel>(d => d.Admin)
    .WithOne(s => s.Host)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.Hostname)
```